# Emulating ARM7(Cortex-A8) image on QEMU in Yocto project

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am a newbie to yoto project; but I had created images for ARM7(Cortex-A8) via Hob or BitBake, now I am trying to emulate this Image to Qemu. I created image using beaglebone available with poky by default and also with `'meta-ti'` layer.

I am working for Sitara Am335x processor. Please direct me in proper way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://mkaczanowski.com/embedded-development-with-qemu-beagleboard-yocto-angstrom-buildroot-where-to-begin/).

Comment: @yegorich: thanks for link, but in that also that is also not successful to emulate the image on QEMU, as mentioned in 'UPDATE', he also mentioned about a bug in newer kernels.

Comment: Do you want to do something am335x specific or do you just need an ARM QEMU, where you can test cross-compiled software?

Comment: @yegorich not so much specific, currently only  want to emulate `Coretex-A8` image QEMU, but with condition to remain under Yocto projects umbrella.

Comment: OK. I see. So far I was testing some cross-compiled packages using Buildroot and its setup for [Versatile](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/board/qemu/arm-versatile). It was working like a charm in the latest Xubuntu. Yocto is still on my TODO list.

Comment: @yegorich: Its nice to see you that you'll also going to work on Yocto.

Comment: Yup :-) The learning curve for Buildroot was not that steep compared to Yocto and BR has curses based menuconfig as Linux kernel. It was a big help from the very beginning. But as some customers ask for Yocto and it is interesting because of package manager, I have put it on my TODO list.